# Created Site Template Does Not Show Up In Solution Gallery

Tags: site-template, site

After creating a site template with contents, SharePoint tells me that everything went OK, and prompts me to go to the Solution Gallery. However, it is empty. Try as I might, I  cannot create a site template through the user interface. The Publishing features are disabled and the "Save site as template" option does appear in the site settings.
If I use PowerShell, I get the following message:

> Exception calling "SaveAsTemplate" with "4" argument(s): "Error generating solution files in temporary directory."

Comment: How did you create the Site Template? Can you post your code for that?

Comment: Like I said, I tried to create the site template either through the user interface, PowerShell and lately through .NET code (SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery).

Comment: I think the operation you are performing does need full control over the disk because as the error suggest that it does need rights to access the temporary directory. You should try with different user or else you can use  `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`  method. Refer this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I am running as a local administrator, farm administrator and the SharePoint farm is even running under the same account. If the temporary location is c:\windows\temp, then it is world-writable anyway.

Comment: Look at the following article: http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2014/05/23/sharepoint-how-to-troubleshoot-issues-with-save-as-template.aspx Is it helpful?

Comment: Thanks, it didn't, but I appreciate your help. Like you said before, it was a matter of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I had to give full permissions to c:\windows\temp. Even though I am an administrator, and so is the SharePoint farm account. Microsoft only knows why.